# UberKit application:openURL:sourceApplication Not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uber-api

I am working with Objective C [Uberkit](https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/UberKit)  library to authenticate users with Uber and call some API methods implemented there in. My app is compiled for iOS 9.

I have successfully integrated the SDK and UberKit authenticates a user by opening safari for the oauth flow. However, safari is stuck after calling the redirect URL with the auth code from Uber.

It seems like the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` method in AppDelegate is never called. Below is how the above method looks in my `AppDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
 {
     NSLog(@"Not Called");
     if([[UberKit sharedInstance] handleLoginRedirectFromUrl:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication])
     {
        return YES;
     }
     else
     {
        return NO;
     }
 }

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
        NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);

       if([[UberKit sharedInstance] handleLoginRedirectFromUrl:url sourceApplication:[url scheme]])
       {
         return YES;
       } 
       return NO;
 }
```

The relevant parts of my Info.plist file are shown below.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.go.UberChat</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>uberkit</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>uber</string>
    <string>https://www.example.com</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections -->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

`https://www.example.com` is my redirect URL so the safari is stuck at `https://www.example.com/?code=3iSwJyxezGi41zliUaNj5SyXYZXYZ` and is not returning to my app so that the rest of the Oauth flow can take place.

Anything I am missing? I tried to compile my app for iOS 8 still no luck.I also tried calling `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url` method in my `AppDelegate` but still no luck.

[image: Enabled Associated Domains]

Comment: are you enabled the assoicated domains in your app id

Comment: am not sure what you mean, kindly clarify further.

Comment: Did you figure out why it's not being called? I'm having a similar issue, and it's only affecting iOS 8 (iOS 9 works as expected).

Answer (score 0):

My problem The problem may be because the SDK is not letting `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` get called. I had a similar issue with Google/SignIn. My solution was to set the pod to `pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 2.0'`. And that fixed my problem.